# How to embed multiple Facebook videos (with React)

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

Reading from [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player), it seems very easy to embed a Facebook video. However, the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` must be just before the script and the `fb-video` class div (from what I've observed). So if I want to embed a video I have to do something like:

```
<div className="card-video-wrapper">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div className="fb-video" data-href="my-video-url" data-show-text="false" data-autoplay="true"></div>
</div>
```

I first thougth that the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` and the script should go just after the opening body tag, but in this way the video keeps hidden at the top of the page.

The problem comes when I want to embed multiple Facebook videos like:

```
<div className="card-video-wrapper">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div className="fb-video" data-href="my-video-url-1" data-show-text="false" data-autoplay="true"></div>
</div>
<div className="card-video-wrapper">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div className="fb-video" data-href="my-video-url-2" data-show-text="false" data-autoplay="true"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, the second one is not displayed.

Probably, `<div id="fb-root"></div>` is supoposed to be placed once, but as I've said, then the video is hidden. Let's see an example:

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    ...

    <div className="card-video-wrapper">
        <div className="fb-video" data-href="my-video-url-1" data-show-text="false" data-autoplay="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div className="card-video-wrapper">
        <div className="fb-video" data-href="my-video-url-2" data-show-text="false" data-autoplay="true"></div>
    </div>

    ...

</body>
```

Inspecting with the navigator console I see these styles applied to the childs of `fb-root` layer:

```
position: absolute;
top: -10000px;
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
```

What is the way to proceed to embed multiple Facebook videos?

**Edit:**

One would think that it has to be related to CSS. However, even removing all CSS rules I see the same problem, the videos are not shown (even just one video) when the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` and the script are placed after the starting body tag.

On the other hand, I've tested it with a simple page (as @hackerrdave suggested), and it works. Now I'm wondering what could be the problem. It's a React application, using some Framework7 components (I'm not sure if this could be relevant).

Comment: Did you try creating an iframe for each video?

Comment: You have `className` instead of `class` in your examples - I understand this is for React, but it may be messing something up with the SDK? Sorry if it is not, I do not have experience with React.

Comment: @Justastudent Yes this is for React. The `className` is replaced with `class` by React.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of **React** is relevant, because the first DOM rendering does not contain any `fb-video` element.

The problem is that the `fb-video` element is rendered when the component receives the elements to render. Then, when the SDK loads, there are no videos to render. If I load the SDK once the elements are received, then the videos are shown.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @CBroe for the tip. A better solution is to use `FB.XFBML.parse();` in the [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and/or [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) function. In this way, I can put the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` and the script after the body tag.

```
componentDidMount() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```

Comment: The SDK has a method specifically for the purpose of rendering content that was added to the document after SDK initialization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: @CBroe - I forgot to mention you in the previous comment. I would award you the bounty if you give an answer.

Comment: Well if that’s all it takes, I’m happy to add one :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround, because I could not find the problem exactly, but I am answering anyway since it leads to something workable. You have been warned.

I found that the Facebook SDK adds a span that somehow sits in the way. By creating your own `iframe` with exactly the same `src` and some other attributes, the video will display properly. If Facebook has a callback somewhere that indicates when it is done loading, we can use that to do exactly that. However, I could not find such a callback so I resolved to using [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

The meat of the solution is in the `onFacebookLoaded` function below. Although I did not use React, I am pretty sure this should work there too. Obviously you can change which attributes you are interested in - there is `allowfullscreen` amongst others, that may be of importance.

The rest of the below code only waits until Facebook has loaded the videos and stops listening for changes after that. It is written in such a way that any number of videos on the page should work.

```js
var onFacebookLoaded = function() {
      // replace .fb-video div with iframe
      var oldFrame = this.querySelector('iframe'),
          newFrame = document.createElement('iframe'),
          attrsWeWant = new Set();
      attrsWeWant.add('src').add('scrolling').add('title')
      .add('width').add('height').add('frameborder');
      if (oldFrame.hasAttributes()) {
        var attrs = oldFrame.attributes;
        for (let i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
          if (attrsWeWant.has(attrs[i].name)) {
            newFrame.setAttribute(attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value);
          }
        }
      }
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(newFrame, this);
    },
    target = document.querySelectorAll('.fb-video'),
    count = target.length,
    observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.target.fbLoadedSeen !== true) {
          onFacebookLoaded.call(mutation.target);
          mutation.target.fbLoadedSeen = true;
          count--;
        }
      });

      // cleanup when all videos have loaded
      if (count === 0) {
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

// connect to updates
for (let i = 0; i < target.length; ++i) {
  observer.observe(target.item(i), {attributes: true});
}
```

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<h1>Video 1</h1>
<div class="fb-video"
     data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/"
     data-width="300"
     data-height="300"
     data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>

<h1>Video 2</h1>
<div class="fb-video"
     data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/"
     data-width="500"
     data-height="400"
     data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
```

Comment: Does not work in my project. It seems that the `span` with the `iframe` is not created for any video.

Comment: So you are saying that the `.fb-video` elements remain empty? Is the `#fb-root` populated with elements? Are you sure the SDK is properly loaded?

Comment: Yes to all your questions.

Comment: Can it be the case that React changes `className` into `class` only after the SDK searches for `.fb-video` elements?

Comment: Um... it could be possible. I'll take a look.

Comment: I've found the problem and posted the answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer did not helped. Your comment gave me a clue to solve the problem. Just voted +1

Answer (score 1):

> [from other answer by OP] The problem is that the fb-video element is rendered when the component receives the elements to render. Then, when the SDK loads, there are no videos to render. If I load the SDK once the elements are received, then the videos are shown.

Yes, the SDK goes through the document and looks for elements to parse *once* on initialization.

But is has a method specifically for the purpose of rendering content that was added to the document after SDK initialization: [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

It can be called without any argument to go look through the whole document again, or it can be passed a DOM element, so that it will only look through a particular DOM subtree.

Answer (score 0):

According to the FB docs, you should only place the SDK and `fb-root` div once:

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then for each video you want to display you can place the embedded video player div:

```
<!-- Your embedded video player code -->
<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"></div>
<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"></div>
```

Comment: That's what I did in the last example. Isn't it? In this way, the player is hidden at the top of the page.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with styles for .card-video-wrapper, the code above embeds 2 videos just fine

Comment: I've edited my question. It doesn't seem to be related to CSS rules.